# Why using alt-tab causes Unity to restart?

Tags: unity, bug-reporting

This have happened to me 4 times. When I use **alt-tab** Unity resets. It doesn't close any apps, but when I click an app that was already open - but minimized - I only can see the minimize/maximize/close buttons and a thin border around the window, it but nothing in it, as on the following picture: 
[image: unity-bug-alt-tab]

This doesn't just happen to one app, but to all my opened minimized apps.

I also want to ask if I should file a bug report?

Comment: try a brand new user with no theme customisation.  Can you reproduce this?  If you can, it is likely to be a bug which you need to report on launchpad.

Comment: I am also suffering from this problem at the moment.

Comment: @Starx or blade19899 - did you file a bug report?  Clearly something is going wrong, and the best way to deal with it is try to isolate it and report it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As fossfreedom says, if you login as a guest user, you'll have a completely fresh user account. If you can get the results there, then that means there is a bug somewhere in the software, most likely Compiz, and then you should report it. Otherwise, it's possible that there is a misconfiguration that causes it.

In order to file a good bug report, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `ubuntu-bug unity`. You'll be asked if the bug you are reporting is a graphical one. Answer yes to that question so that information about your graphics card, driver, etc can also be appended.

Please make sure you've installed all upgrades and that you can still reproduce the problem before filing bugs.

From your screenshot, I'd say it's more than likely that the issue has to do with Compiz. But it is not impossible that it is a misconfiguration, so check with a guest account first.